# windows sometimes black

Tags: window-manager

Sometimes windows, dialogs (gnome, KDE) go black and only the decoration as the titlebar remains and its buttons work as well. It happens a few times a within 10 hours continuously working. More or less twice a hour.

here the setup:

- tripple monitor, NVIDIA default driver
- Ubuntu latest LTS (14.010), x64 with no tweaks or mods/other window-manager installed. All on default, just Oracle-Java instead of OpenJDK.
- ## lshw -C display: PCI (sysfs)

  *-display
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: GK107 [GeForce GT 640]
     vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
     version: a1
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
     resources: irq:64 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fb000000-fb07ffff

other notices:

- It comes with multiple Java-Applications (PHP/Webstorm, Eclipse) and seems to affect other applications as well: Chrome, Krusader and also gnome dialogs or any other gnonme based applications.
- Keyboard goes off in Java applications, no idea this is related but it happens the same rate as the window problem.

  - it came with the 14.4 update

current solution:

- press escape to close dialog or application (crucial sometimes) and redo the step.

As I don't have anything special installed I'd love to know what to do about, its sometimes more frequent and really annoying.

ps: there is a duplicate about but not well described or supported: https://askubuntu.com/questions/553293/windows-sometimes-go-black

Comment: What graphics and drivers do you have? (you can use `lshw -C display` and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/602623/edit) it into your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1072206) in compiz. As far as I am aware of the current daily image of 15.04 should have this fixed. You could try that and see whether that helps.

Comment: Unity uses compiz, but Gnome and KDE use other window managers...

Comment: Oh yeah that's true. My bad.

Comment: Hi, turning off animations via Compiz-Settings solved it :-)

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)